# Accidentally mislabeled a job; how to fix it?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I posted an [SRE job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/531446/senior-site-reliability-engineer-leolabs) on Stack Overflow, but mislabeled it by putting a field named "Role" and filling it as "system administrator".

The job is for a site reliability engineer and not for system administration. I did not add that label, and during the setup, you are not given a chance to add this role. I only saw this after the job was posted.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you post a link I can fix that for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/531446/senior-site-reliability-engineer-leolabs?so_medium=Talent&so_source=TalentApi

Comment: thanx, the link is above, but it would be nice if I knew how to fix this myself

Answer (score 1):

That field is auto-generated by machine learning on our end. It's unfortunately not editable by users but I've gone ahead and removed it for you. In the future, you can [open a support ticket](https://stackoverflow.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/26).

Comment: maybe they should simply make that a field the customer can edit themselves.